# What default screensaver does a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 have, and how to check if it is active?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 22.04, lock-screen, screensaver

I had the impression that Ubuntu had Gnome screensaver or xscreensaver by default. But when I tried `gnome-screensaver-command --query`, I'm shown the error "Command 'gnome-screensaver-command' not found". When I try `xscreensaver`, I'm shown "Command 'xscreensaver' not found".
When I do `ps -aef | grep "screensaver"`, I'm shown this process running `/usr/libexec/gsd-screensaver-proxy`.

I know I can install gnome-screensaver and query it with `gnome-screensaver-command -q` to check if the screensaver is active. But my objective is to know what screensaver is installed by default in Ubuntu (when it's a fresh install), and how to query to check if the screensaver is active?

*Original objective: I'm creating an app that asks users to rest their eyes periodically, and it needs to know when the screen is locked. At least in Mint Cinnamon, I can simply use `cinnamon-screensaver-command -q` to query if the screen is locked. But in Ubuntu, do I have to ask the user to install gnome screensaver, or is there a pre-installed screensaver or some other method to check if the screen is locked?*